# Getting all nulls when reading file with list

Tags: java, file, arraylist, null

Hi there is problem with reading a file. My file content is:

```
Alcohol 0,000425 0,000385 0,00003 0,89.
```

It shows that all variables are equal to null.
I can't find mistakes in this code. Maybe somtehing is wrong with filter or foreach loop.

```
public class FileReading  {
    List<Double> Mass1 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Double> Mass2 = new ArrayList<>();
    List <Double> Voulume = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Double> Height = new ArrayList<>(); 

    void Reading(String name,int sk) throws IOException{ 
        List<String> Material= new ArrayList<>();
        Material = Files.lines(Paths.get("D:/Desktop/NewFolder/26laboratorinis.txt")).
                filter(s->s.contains(name))
                .map(s ->s.substring(sk)).collect(Collectors.toList());

        for(String number : Material){

            String[] l = number.split(" ");
            Mass1.add(Double.parseDouble(l[0]));
            Mass2.add(Double.parseDouble(l[1]));
            Volume.add(Double.parseDouble(l[2]));
            Height.add(Double.parseDouble(l[3]));
        }   

    }
    public void setMass1(List<Double> PAM) {
        this.Mass1 = PAM;
    }

    public void setMass2(List<Double> TAM) {
        this.Mass2 = TAM;
    }
    public void setVolume(List<Double> T) {
        this.Volume =T;
    }

    public void setHeight(List<Double> VSA) {
        this.Height = VSA;
    }
    public List<Double> getMass1() {
        return Mass1;
    }
    public List<Double> getMass2() {
        return Mass2;
    }
    public List<Double> getVolume() {
        return Volume;
    }
    public List<Double> getHeight() {
        return Height;
    }

}
```

Comment: Learn about Java naming conventions. propery/variable names should start with lower case character

Comment: Use a Debugger to find out what is happening

Comment: you have misspelled the variable declariation: Voulume

Comment: besides variables name conventions and that typing error everything else looks good, you can also give us the value of those parameters "name" and 
 "sk" if you need further help

Comment: I cannot reproduce. On my computer, when correcting the typo in `Voulume` and deleting the period after 0,89, your program runs nicely and fills the numbers into the four `ArrayList`s.

Answer (score 0):

Which values do you pass to Reading method when you call it?

Anyway:

`Files.lines` - read all lines from file as a Stream.
After that you put each line in `filter` method. So, if line doesn't contains your parameter *name* it'll just "throw away" this line.

After that method `map` convert all filtered lines to `s.substring(sk)`.

And finally `collect` method convert your stream to List.

So, maybe you passed name which doesn't content in any line of your document, that's why you're getting null.

Comment: They'd be getting an empty List, not null.

Comment: Maybe there is other problem. How should I use these variables in other class? ReadingFile file; file.getMass1().get(0); ?

Comment: Yes, @LOGO, that looks right, except you should call `Reading()` before you call any of the getters, to give the object a chance to read anything from the file.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou, yes, you're right, it should be just empty list, not null.

Comment: @LOGO, can you provide method from which you call `Reading` method and get null? I think it'll be easier in times to solve your issue!